# bootstrap 3 div is not responsive in mobile and tablet and are too small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

this is my form, when i show in my pc it has a good size and the form inputs are in the same line, but in my tablet (7") it preserves the same size and the inputs are too small there. How can i do to get my inputs bigger in the tablet? each input as wide as the screen. Thanks

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-sm-5">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2" id="divprecio">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2" id="divcantidad">

   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">

   </div>
```

Comment: Give us an example in jsFiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mario28/5f847jn7/

Answer (score 0):

I have added a class col-xs-12 for making it full width on small screens, and I think it's working as you required. Kindly check.
And if it's not taking full width on PC then it's because  col-MD-6 **col-MD-offset-3** offset is added which is maybe cause this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12"><div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Email">
  </div></div>


        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12" id="divprecio"><div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Newlebel</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Newlebel">
  </div></div>


        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12" id="divcantidad"><div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Fillnew</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Password">
  </div></div>


        <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">

          <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Fillabc</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="text">
  </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```